# Am I correct in how equipment level affects its stats?

Tags: borderlands-series

Am I correct in how equipment level affects its stats?

I know that rarity affects things too, but that's easier to grind for than level.

Since I don't want to make a separate question for each game, I'm tagging this with the whole series.

---

Guns + Grenade Mods: I assume that basically, only Damage is dependent on the weapon's level, while Accuracy, Reload Speed, Fire Rate, etc, are level-independent?

Shields: Well, the effects depend on the game, but Capacity + Recharge Rate might be the only dependent variable, and Nova / Spike damage?

Class Mods: I really only want to know for Pre-Sequel, but it seems that skill boost numbers are level-locked, while other stats, like [Celestial Baroness](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Celestial_Baroness) Ammo Regen... Well, I hope I can get 1.3 on a Legendary one, no matter my level...

Oz Kits: Basically everything about it is level-locked? Oz Capacity, Slam Damage, a Bomber's Free Grenade Chance...

Comment: Also if you haven't yet played Borderlands 2 definitely consider playing it is the sequel to Borderlands : Pre-sequel, i'm gonna say spoilers but it's whole main story is about someone from Pre-sequel.

Comment: @I.LOVE.BORDERLANDS - Well, Pre-Sequel is slightly spoilery, with the opening cutscene, but I've got every game but Tales, so woo! Borderlands!

Comment: Same, I still haven't got tales. But I'm going to buy Borderlands 3 after Covid-19. I heard from a friend that it is the best one so far and i'm hyped to play it.

Comment: @I.LOVE.BORDERLANDS - For all that I dislike Epic Games, getting their free game and using the resultant coupon on Super Deluxe Borderlands 3, is ~75% off. Steam has only had 50% off sales. ... The chance expires in June, so... Yeah.

Comment: So that means you don't like Fortnite? He he

Answer (score 1):

Hi Again Malady if you remember me... I answered another question you asked about repeatable missions in Pre-Sequel. Being a pro lv 70 in Pre-Sequel. Yes you're right about almost everything. You forgot that elemental damage in all kinds of items grows higher over levels and about Oz Kits, most of their perks ( Bonus Damage, Bober's free grenade, etc...)  Are not level-locked but are rather rarity-locked, legendaries have bigger bonuses. Also Oxygen capacity barely gets higher, I remember that since Lv 34 I have only went from 168 to 181 capacity, and my OZ kit is Lv 68. But you are pretty accurate about Mod Classes. So yeah you're 90% right I guess.

Comment: Cool! I've seen you around, being very Borderlands Focused! Well, the name fits! :) ... I'd advise spacing out of info, but thanks for the info in any case!

Comment: @Malady You're Very Welcome ;)